# Can't show non-English characters in IIS

Tags: iis, ftp, iis-8

All non-English characters show as '?'. I tried `SET Allow UTF-8` in IIS to false, but this did not work.

My system is Server 2012 r2 — English platform

Comment: Does it show an actual question mark, or the "question mark in a box" Unicode replacement character?

Answer (score 0):

"Allow UTF8" needs to be enabled on IIS for you to be able to see non-English characters.

And you also need to use a FTP client that supports UTF8. It seems that the FTP command in Windows does not support UTF8, since it shows "question-mark in a box" for non-English characters, when I try to list files with Chinese characters in the filename.

But the FileZilla FTP Client does support UTF8, and in my test I was able to both see the file and download it.